# How to write to HttpContext.Response.Body on .NET Core 3.1.x

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httpresponse

I've been trying to write or set the HttpContext.Response.Body but to no avail. Most of the samples I found is using the Body.WriteAsync but the paramaters are different then the example. I tried converting my string to byte[] but the text doesn't show on my Response.Body.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> trying to write or set the HttpContext.Response.Body but to no avail.

You can refer to the following code, which works well for me.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{

    //for testing purpose
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");

    await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    //...
```

Besides, you can call [`HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to write the given text to the response body.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    //for testing purpose
    await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpContext.Response, "Hello World");

    //...
```

Comment: Which `IActionResult` should be used when the action writes directly to `Response.Body`?

Comment: @Dai the protected `Empty` property which is a singleton for the `EmptyResult`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not actual, but as mentioned before you can use the extension method from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace.

```
public static Task WriteAsync(this HttpResponse response, string text, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

So your code will looks like (this is a bit simpler syntax):

```
HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(defaultUnauthorizedResponseHtml);
```